# Change line size of a single plot inside facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to change the size of a particular line, inside a single `facet_grid`, and  keep the others unchanged. This in order to "highlight" more a line.

Fake data:

```
set.seed(123)
my_data <- data.frame(
  time = 1:100,
  a = runif(100, min = 0, max = 10),
  b = runif(100, min = 0, max = 20),
  c = runif(100, min = 0, max = 30)
)


library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(key~., scales = "free") +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)
```

[image]

In this example, I'd like the `b` plot to have a bigger line `size`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by creating a new vector having the repeated sizes:

```
linesize = rep(c(0, 1, 0), each=100) # externally define the sizes
# note that a,c will have size=0 while b size=1
```

This will be used inside the `geom_line` call:

```
my_data %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line(size = linesize) + # here we can pass linesize
  facet_grid(key~., scales = "free") +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This approach has the short coming that if you have more plots inside the grid, you'll have to figure out where is your bigger plot, an manually set the sizes: `linesize <- rep(c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1), each=100)`  if you have `8` plots and want to change the `4th`.